# YUI compressor regex confusion

Tags: regex, yui, concatenation, minify, yui-compressor

I'm using YUI compressor to minify and combined some JS files. I can minify individual files no problem using this:

```
TimPeterson$ -jar yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar /assets/js/input1.js -o /assets/js/output.js --charset utf-8
```

However, when I tried to combined and minify multiple JS files i got this help message:

```
Multiple files can be processed using the following syntax:
TimPeterson$ java -jar yuicompressor.jar -o '.js$:-min.js' *.js
```

If I want to compress and minify `/assets/js/input1.js` **AND** `/assets/js/input2.js` how would that look with this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java -jar yuicompressor.jar -o '.js$:-min.js' /assets/js/input1.js /assets/js/input2.js

This should generate /assets/js/input1-min.js and /assets/js/input2-min.js